# Materializing an existing view in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, materialized-views

I have an existing view I need materialized. Ideally, I would drop the view and create a materialized one, but dropping the view would require a cascade drop and that would create a lot more work.

Is there an expression to change the view to a materialized one?

Comment: NO there is not.  However, there is a script which **may** come to your aid: [save_restore_dependencies](https://gist.github.com/mateuszwenus/11187288). Since you are changing the object type you are like to need slight modification, but it may be worth your time to investigate.